# Directory Redirect to HTML Document not working

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

On a website I have a directory **service-name** which I don't want people to have access to, since it just stores css files, images and pdfs. Further more, in a different folder on the site, at the web root, there is a page **service-name.html**.

To stop the directory listing, in the **service-name** folder, I have included a .htaccess file and an index.html file.

Within the .htaccess file I have put `Options -Indexes` to disable the directory listing, and then put in `RewriteRule   ^index.html    http://www.example.com/service-name.html [R=301,L]`

So in short I am trying to redirect the search for the directory to a root level html page. It is not working though. I get a blank page with the **service-name** directory, which I guess works adequatley because my desire to stop people accessing a directory has come to fruition, but it does not redirect straight to the desired page, which I thought it would have if I included the **index.html** page in the directory and redirected that?

But when you search for **service-name/index.html** that redirects properly, so I have clearly missed something! A sharp prod in the right direction would be of use!

Thanks

Comment: If you want to redirect the entire directory then you need to use 

`RewriteRule ^dirName/.+$ http://example.com/page.html` .

Comment: @starkeen - thanks for responding - would that need to be in my main site htaccess or the directory one? - bearing in mind as well that I only want the individual web page for the directory to redirect, without messing up any of the images and css :)